# Sort array values after grouping - mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have grouped data with favourites, and I have pushed into array.I want to sort the array with object key for example name,email,or age.

```
 {
                        $group:
                        {
                            _id: "$favourite",
                            favourite: { $first: "$favourite" },
                            data: {
                                $push: {
                                    "name": "$name",
                                    "email": "$email",
                                    "age": "$age"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I tried with this below code, but its not working.

```
  { "$sort": { "data.name": 1 } }
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) before [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "name": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$favourite",
    "favourite": { "$first": "$favourite" },
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "name": "$name",
        "email": "$email",
        "age": "$age"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```